# MVC tracking fields such as Author and Editor (Created By and Modified By)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking for the best way to track the Author and Editor fields for all the entities in my database.

I started by creating a base model which all my models inherit from:

```
public class DatabaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Modified By")]
    public ApplicationUser Editor { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Modified")]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

This works good, but I have to set these fields in every action in my controllers. How can I set these fields every time an item in my database is updated or edited? I am aware that I could override `Add` in my `DbContext`, but I have no idea how to get the `ApplicationUser` from the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` in my `DbContext`. I have tried:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    : base(options)
    {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        this.httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        DatabaseEntity dbEntity = (entity as DatabaseEntity);
        if (dbEntity != null)
        {
            dbEntity.Created = DateTime.Now;
            dbEntity.Creator = await userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContext.User);
        }

        return base.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

but this gives error because `userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContext.User);` requires an `await` and `public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)` is not async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting current user, you should not use `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. With commenting `dbEntity.Creator = await userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContext.User);`, you will get error **A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'CoreDb.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.** due to that you accessing `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` in `ApplicationDbContext`.

I suggest you try get the current user by querying `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` with current user name.

Here is a simple code:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{       
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }       
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public override EntityEntry<TEntity> Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        DatabaseEntity dbEntity = (entity as DatabaseEntity);
        var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        if (dbEntity != null)
        {
            dbEntity.Created = DateTime.Now;
            dbEntity.Creator = userName == null ? null : ApplicationUser.Where(user => user.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return base.Add(entity);    
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
    }        
}
```

Comment: As soon as I get home today I will give this a try. It looks like it should work.